# Jquery - .forEach() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have created this little interaction for one of the platforms at work - http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/426/

It works fine in all browsers apart form IE8. When I run the console it seems to be this section that it is having problems with...

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(l, function(item) {
        a.push(jQuery(item).text());
   });
```

Can someone show me an IE8 friendly alternative so I can make it compatible for the versions required?

Comment: why not you use jQuery instead of prototype

Comment: @Sarfaraz: The `prototype` in this case is not the library, but the keyword in Javascript.

Comment: @Sarfaraz Also what's wrong with using prototype?

Comment: @nickyduck  actually am confuse a little bit with prototype and trying to understand prototype

Comment: @Gufaa am not understand what are you saying

Comment: @TheMechanic: Sorry, didn't get a notification about your comment as you spelled my name wrong... The `prototype` in `Array.prototype.forEach` has nothing to do with the Prototype library, it's a keyword in Javascript.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [`jQuery.each` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
jQuery.each(l, function(index, item){
  a.push(jQuery(item).text());
});
```

If the target array is empty from start, you can use the [`jQuery.map` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) for this instead:

```
var a = jQuery.map(l, function(item){
  return jQuery(item).text();
});
```

Comment: Now the console is saying that it doesn't support index = a.indexOf(current) + 1;
       if (index < 0 ||  index >= l.length) {
           index = 0; @Guffa
       }

Comment: @Milo-J: `Array.indexOf` is another method recently added. Use the `jQuery.inArray` method instead. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: I have tried to do it but it will not work. could you please have a look? http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/428/ @Guffa

Comment: @Milo-J: When you get the text from the element using the `text` method, you don't get the same thing back as what you put in using the `html` method, so your code will never find the text in the array.

Comment: that `l` is very confusing.

Comment: @deddu: Perhaps, but I used exactly the same variable name as in the question on purpose.

Answer (score 45):

If all you want is `forEach()` in IE8:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.forEach != 'function') {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback){
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        callback.apply(this, [this[i], i, this]);
      }
    };
}
```

This will behave [as expected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in any browser that doesn't have it built-in.

Comment: Up voted this as when in comes to a large scale project, some times its easier and safer to help correct the faulty browser instead of trying to correct code which is not actually faulty

Comment: It would be better to use polyfill at the link provided. That code has been perfected.

Comment: I found useful your answer but it couldn't work for me (IE11, Windows 10). It says the "object" (a basic array) doesn't handle the `forEach` method. I tried `console.log` the `typeof` of the function and the `function` itself and it is defined as a function with `[native code]`.

Answer (score 4):

forEach is not supported in IE 8, instead you can use a regular loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) {
   // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the forEach method is only available from IE9. You should use the jQuery version "each()" in order to offer support to older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with IE8 and here is how I solved it!

First of all wanted to loop and get data from **JSON array** object.
Take look of original which is working well in Firex, chrome and latest IE but not IE8

```html
            data.children.forEach(function(item) {
              //javascript: console.log(item);
              console.log(data.children);
              attachRel(item, '1' + (data.children.length > 1 ? 1 : 0));
            });
```

**Here is the solution that I developed after a long day of struggle**

```js
            $.each(data.children, function () {

                attachRel(this, '1' + (data.children.length > 1 ? 1 : 0));
            });
```